# AT Command to disable delivery reports

Tags: python, sms

I'm working on a SMS daemon for sending and receiving SMS. I'm using a (slightly modified) version of `python-gsmmodem-new` as my GSM-Library.

The problem I encountered was that with every Message a Delivery Report seems to be requested.

The strange thing is, the reports are seemingly disabled at modem initialization. I double checked the code, it's using the command

`AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0`

for initialization, which should be alright. After consulting the GSM Documentation I learned that for Delivery Reports Bit 5 has to be set, which is 32 in decimal, so the code for Delivery reports has to be `AT+CSMP=49,167,0,0`.

Is there something I could have missed?

As my Service Provider charges 25 cents per Report and there are roughly 800 Message per Month this is quite costly, and i can't really charge this to the customer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The `CSMP`-setting was correct, but for whatever reason i had to set the modem into text mode with `AT+CMGF=1` for it to work properly.

Comment: https://forum.sierrawireless.com/t/hilo-how-to-get-sms-delivery-report/6467 ... here's a confirmation that the CSMP settings are ignored in PDU mode